# How do I disable H2 in the Play Framework

Tags: playframework

We are using Play with Objectify/GAE and do not need any RDBMS. How do I disable the db service (H2)?

Answer (score 0):

in `application.conf`,just remove or comment out the line

```
db=mem
```

This is the line that specifies that H2 should be used, so by removing it, it will solve your problem.

Comment: I was able to do it by disabling the plugin. `public class GAEPlugin extends PlayPlugin {

    public PlayDevEnvironment devEnvironment = null;
    public boolean prodGAE;

    @Override
    public void onLoad() {
        // Remove Jobs from plugin list
        for (ListIterator<PlayPlugin> it = Play.plugins.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            PlayPlugin p = it.next();
            if (p instanceof JobsPlugin || p instanceof DBPlugin) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }`